# Angular 8 typescript number value coming through as string

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm sure I'm just doing something stupid but I can't see it.

I have the following html:

```
<input type="number" (change)="changeEventDate(event, dateField.value)" [value]="date" #dateField />
```

And typescript:

```
const date: number;

...

changeEventDate(event: Event, date: number) {
  console.log(typeof date); // This logs "string"
}
```

}

So I'm passing in a number to [value],
it's an input of type number and
the typescript method takes in a number parameter...
how is it still a string?

(I know can just cast it to fix the issue, but I'm trying to understand why it's not working as expected.)

And I guess, in case it's important:

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.20",
"@angular/cli": "~8.3.20",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
"@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
"typescript": "~3.5.3"
```

Comment: the input value is always string do like this `(change)="changeEventDate(event, +dateField.value)"`

Comment: can you try this : `(change)="changeEventDate($event, $event.target.value)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the `dateField.value` you will be getting the DOM value, which will always be a string.

There are couple things you can do to make things better, First thing (best thing in Angular) which is **two way data binding**.

- make your `date` variable `public` and then in your html `<input [(ngModel)]="date" ...`
- And in your function `console.log(typeof this.date);`

Another thing (just a workaround), is to keep your code as is, and just convert the passed in value to a number `console.log(typeof Number(date));`

Answer (score 0):

Here you're getting the value from input field `dateField.value` it returns the string value. You can fix it changing to `changeEventDate(event, +dateField.value)`